# Strange .NET DateTime issue (Month is 00??)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

As you can see below, I encounter a strange behaviour.

I am trying to instantiate a DateTime with a year, a month and a day (easy!).

But in debug mode, Date displays 00 for the month, while Month displays 4!

Maybe a configuration problem in my solution? I work in an ASP .NET MVC 4 application.

[image: 00 instead of 04]

[image: Date and Month differences]

Comment: That's odd. It feel like a debug display problem though since the internal `Month` property is correct.

Comment: My bet is your windows culture settings uses lowercase `mm` for month :)

Comment: try new _DateTime(2013-04-24);_

Comment: Silvermind said it. They set your Windows settings to display dates as "day-**minute**-year hour:minute:second". And minute is `0`, as we see. Do you have the same problem in the taskbar? Or maybe it is a setting somewhere else?

Comment: @im_a_noob So, `new DateTime(1985)`?

Comment: @Silvermind comment seems correct. You can verify it by trying to use your own format. For example: var d = new DateTime(2013,4,24);
d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); If this is indeed the case then just go to the regional setting of windows and update the Format to use "MM" instead of "mm".

Comment: It could have been that, but here it was a ShortDatePattern overload. Thanks guys it helped a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of a bad format string somewhere, probably confusing `"MM"` (month) with `"mm"` (minute), like @Silvermind said in a comment to the question. I can reproduce the problem like this:

```
var badCulture = new CultureInfo("");
badCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-mm-yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = badCulture;

var testDate = new DateTime(2013, 4, 24);  // debug and rest mouse over variable
```

So check if someone used a bad format string somewhere.

Comment: You are right Jeppe! The ShortDatePattern has been overriden in my solution (!). Thanks a lot! :)